# How to add Foreign keys?

Tags: mysql

So I made all of my tables already and just found out about Foreign keys and now I know I need them.

How would I add a relation between 2 columns from 2 tables? I see multiple variations of how Foreign key is used, how would I use mine in my case?

Comment: you didn't explain what your case is.

Comment: I'm basically just asking for a query to add a foreign key to a database... I see multiple variations of it and asking for help in to which query would be the best one for me.

Comment: Keep in mind "and now I know I need them" usually translates to "I think they're really cool and I want to try them out" which is often an entirely different thing. Read up on the pros and cons of foreign keys before committing to them. They don't come for free.

Comment: and how would anyone tell you which one to use if you don't show us what are the different solutions and in which case you want to use it?

Comment: I just need it so, if for example we delete a user using user_id, then it will delete all of the records in all of the other tables that are referenced to it. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) query to modify the table to add the foreign key constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (col_in_yourTable) REFERENCES otherTable (col_in_otherTable);
```

The syntax after `ADD CONSTRAINT` is essentially the same as the `CONSTRAINT` clause of `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Thanks! :) I appreciate it